# SQLite library variant only for dump

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, visual-c++

I am developing application which reads (only reads!) data from SQLite database file; but size of result binary is limited. I've tried to make SQLite smaller (by specifying SQLITE_OMIT_* preprocessor definitions), but size of result EXE is 490kb, which is enormous for my purpose. Is there a small SQLite library specified only for reading all stored data? No requests, no optimizations, just reading all tables data from database file.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Is that a Release build exe that's 490K? What is it without SQLite?

Comment: Yes, in Release. It is 280k without SQLite.

Comment: So it's adding 210K, is that really too much? I would have thought it would only link in what you're using, but I'm not too sure if that's definite. I guess you've [seen this blog](http://posted-stuff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/minimal-sqlite-library-size.html)?

Comment: It is really too much, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: Ok understood - from the blog link I posted it seems like you're pretty much as low as you can go. No possibility of savings elsewhere?

Comment: No possibility. There is much more functionality, which is unfortunately essential and can't be stripped out.

Comment: I see, it looks like the 210K is [around the SQLite ballpark](http://www.sqlite.org/footprint.html#relfootprint) - I hope someone else has an alternative but I'm sorry I can't suggest more.